# Yii image upload maxsize

Tags: file-upload, yii, php

```
$uploadedFile5=CUploadedFile::getInstance($campaign,'image5');    

array('campaign_image,campaign_thumbnail,campaign_imagea,campaign_imageb', 'file','types'=>'jpg, gif, png', 'maxSize' => 5 * 1024 * 1024, 'tooLarge'=>'The file was larger than 5MB. Please upload a smaller file.','allowEmpty'=>true),
```

Hi all. Above is my rules for validate for image uploading. However, it still only allow me to upload file with maxsize 2MB due to upload_max_filesize in my php is 2mb.

Is there anyway allow me upload image which is larger than 2MB other than edit my php.ini file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are <strike>two</strike> one way<strike>s</strike> to modify **upload_max_filesize** without editing php.ini ...

<strike>In your PHP file:</strike>

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M');
```

Or in your .htaccess file:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
```

Comment: `upload_max_filesize` is `PHP_INI_PERDIR`, meaning it cannot be set at runtime (it makes no logical sense otherwise, file uploads are received and processed *before* your script runs).

Answer (score 0):

use

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M
```

in your php.ini